# Pre-Authentication not working if another user is logged in - Spring security

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

When a user is pre-authenticated on one website (Site A) and clicks the link to my other site (Site B) everything works like it should do.

Except if there is a user logged on to Site B on the same browser then the PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter is never called. So what I need is the pre-auth log in to overwrite current user if there is any.

I am sending two tokens as a URL parameters and use them to authenticate users. Is there anyone who knows if I can get the pre-authetication filter to overwrite current user or some other ways to do it?

Relevant code:

Security-app-context.xml

```
<beans:bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="userDetailsServiceWrapper"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter" class="MyProject.login.PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"  class="MyProject.login.UserDetailServicePreAuth" />
```

PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter

```
public class PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if(request.getParameter("idnumber") != null){
        return request.getParameter("idnumber");
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String[] credentials = new String[3];
    if(request.getParameter("idnumber") != null){
        credentials[0] = request.getParameter("token");
        credentials[1] = request.getParameter("A");
        credentials[2] = request.getServletPath();
        return credentials;
    }
    return null;
}
```

AuthenticationUserDetailsService

```
public class UserDetailServicePreAuth implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<Authentication> {

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserDetails(Authentication authentication) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    String id = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
    String[] p = (String[]) authentication.getCredentials();
    String token = p[0];
    User user = new User();
    user = UserData.getUserPreAuth(id, token);

    return user;
}
```

But the problem is that when user is logged in and a url with the parameters (idnumber and token) are called then nothing happens, the URL parameters just gets ignored and the user which is logged in just is still logged in.

Is there a way that user can be overwritten with this approach?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [`checkForPrincipalChanges`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.html#setCheckForPrincipalChanges%28boolean%29) property to `true` if you want an existing login session to be invalidated.

```
<beans:bean id="PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter" class="MyProject.login.PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="checkForPrincipalChanges" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Sorry if I am being redundant but where would i call this code? And I forgot to say it in the question but I also have a form login, will that work with this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this makes the application call the AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter in any request and then the request variable does not have any parameters, except in the first request, so it will overwrite the login and I can´t even log-in once. So it seems like this does not work except if I can make the authentication only happen if there are some parameters in the request or else nothing happens. Do you have idea if I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't do enough here, so I don't have the privilege to reply to your comment in a comment. The answer @Luke Taylor provides is actually enough and helped me with an issue that I was having. I'm just answering your comment question you made on Apr 8 '15 at 15:13.

A way to achieve what you want is to override the AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter method. Within it, you can do your parameter checks of all your requests. Here's a pseudo code of what I mean...

```
// This is the override
doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    if (request has param I'm looking for) {
        // This says, "perform the authentication"
        super.doFilter(request, response, chain)
    }
    else {
        // This says, "skip this part of the filter chain"
        chain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
}
```